# Как Google относится к распространению приложения в конкретном регионе?

Tags: разработка-игр, google-play, playmarket, ads, google-play-games

В общем я написал игру и выложил ее в гугл плей. Возникла проблема с распространением. А если конкретно: Как гугл отнесется к тому, что я буду распространять игру в виде обьявления(листовки). Грубо говоря клеить объявления на забор с ссылкой на саму игру(в виде qr-кода)?
Возможно гугл плей где-то об этом упоминает, если знаете киньте ссылку.

Comment: Главное оплату мимо google не принимать. На рекламу самого приложения в сторонних ресурсах им нет дела.

Comment: Ему пофиг. Но зачем такие сложности? Кальмара хотите воссоздать в отдельно взятом регионе?

Comment: Arty Morris, Мне не понятно ваше выражение "Кальмара хотите воссоздать". Сложности - да я их люблю. И еще мне интересно как отреагируют люди именно с моей деревни. Можете считать это экспериментом :)